# how to provide username and password in tnsnames.ora

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, odbc, database-administration

I have connected oracle server database in excel with the help of  oracle instant client software and i am getting table and data but whenever i am restarting excel to connect with oracle database it is asking username and password so i want to save the username and password so is this possible to provide username and password in tnsnames.ora file itself?

```html
ASDCOM=
 (description=
   (address_list=
     (address = (protocol = TCP)(host = 10.1.1.128)(port = 1521))
   )
 (connect_data =
   (service_name=ASDCOM)
 )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to save username and password in tnsnames.ora file. you should fix it in excel.

Comment: MOHSEN do you have any idea regarding this how to save username and password in excel

Comment: mohsen can i save username and password in .odc file

Comment: as i checked excel in  data tab/from other sources/from data connect wizard/ other advanced  and then click next there are connection tab you can save username password with an option there.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot save username and password in tnsnames.ora instead you can save username and password in .odc file which is generated when you provide username and password in excel data connection wizard and click on savePasswordInFile checkbox.

Comment: what this .odc file located after generating

Comment: C:\Users\IT-Prog3\Documents\My Data Sources this is the default location

Answer (score 0):

You can save the username and password **manually only** for Tracking and it **will not reflect** anywhere in tnsnames.ora

like this

```
SEADEV.WORLD = (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.10.10)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVER = DEDICATED)
   (SERVICE_NAME = TEST)
)
 (USER ID=myUser) (PASSWORD=myPaswoer)
)
```